# Update Trigger PL/SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I create the following tables:

```
create table products

(
        code             varchar(9),
        group_code       varchar(9),
        price            number,  

CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

I created a trigger , for that the price per group of products does not exceed 100 dollars:

```
create or replace trigger nomore100
before insert or update on products
for each row
declare
cursor c_total is
select group_code, sum(price) as total_price
from products
where group_code=:new.group_code
group by group_code;
v_total c_total%rowtype;
begin
for v_total in c_total loop
    if v_total.total_price+:new.price > 100 then
        raise_application_error(-20150,'No more than 100 dollars');
    end if;
end loop;
end nomore100;
/
```

The trigger works for inserts, but when i try to do a update:

update products set price=120 where code='PX1';
Oracle return:

> "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

Thanks for any suggestions or answers, have a nice day!

Now I try the following trigger from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372393/update-trigger-pl-sql-oracle):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER compound_trigger
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON products
COMPOUND TRIGGER

  TYPE group_code_t   IS TABLE OF products.group_code%TYPE INDEX BY varchar2(100);
  v_group_codes          group_code_t;

     BEFORE EACH ROW IS
     BEGIN
        v_group_codes( :new.group_code ) := :new.group_code;
     END BEFORE EACH ROW;

     AFTER STATEMENT IS
        v_total NUMBER;
     BEGIN
      -- for each updated department check the restriction
      FOR code IN v_group_codes.FIRST .. v_group_codes.LAST
      LOOP
         SELECT sum(price) INTO v_total FROM products WHERE code = group_code;
         IF v_total > 100 THEN
            raise_application_error(-20123, 'ERROR MORE THAN 100 DOLLARS');
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
     END AFTER STATEMENT;

END compound_trigger;
/
```

But I get the same error:

> "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

Comment: Basically you cannot access the table being updated / inserted to in an `on update` / `on insert` row-level trigger. [Workarounds exist](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm), though [none of them are too nice](http://harmfultriggers.blogspot.com/2011/11/workarounds-for-ora-04091.html). Autonomous transactions used to be my favorite.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the mutating table error with your compound trigger.  I take it you dropped the trigger `nomore100`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward its true Oracle give me that error because i had other trigger using the table products. Thanks but if I have a product of 50 dollars and i add other product of 60 dollars, oracle dont give me the error

Comment: @Python241820: that's quite probably because in your query `SELECT sum(price) INTO v_total...` the `code` in `code = group_code` is being interpreted as the column `code` rather than the loop variable `code`.  I suggest changing the name of the loop variable.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the question you asked a few hours ago.  Feel free to edit your earlier question if you have more code to share.  If these are not duplicates, can you explain exactly what the difference is?